# Model structure for dga of (endormorphism) vector bundle valued differential forms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, model-categories, curvature, differential-graded-algebras

I was browsing and came across [this discussion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+dg-algebras) on the model structure for a dga. They mostly explain the commutative case but then say some things about the non-commutative case.

**Context** Consider a vector bundle with connection on a smooth manifold and the dga of endomorphis-bundle-valued forms on the manifold whose differential is induced by the connection. A map of manifolds induces a map (in the other direction) of the above curved dgas. My question below has these curved dgas in mind.

**Question** Is there a clean way to describe some model structure on the category of these curved dgas?

Comment: I do not think I've ever encountered an interesting model structure on curved dg-algebras.   There is a standard model structure on dg-algebras (say, over a commutative ring), but it only works for uncurved dg-algebras.  Curved dg-coalgebras over a field have a model structure described in Section 9.3 of "Two kinds of derived categories, Koszul duality, and comodule-contramodule correspondence", https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2621 , but that's a much simpler case than that of curved dg-algebras.

Comment: Thank you @LeonidPositselski. In section 3 of our paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.15275.pdf, we present a sort of ad-hoc cohomology definition for a (non-commutative, over a commutative ring) curved dga and then discuss chain homotopies etc. We show that it has some nice properties, but it wasn't the main point of the paper. I want to continue this work but before I feel I'm building something from scratch I wanted to check I wasn't unaware of some already-digestible version. 

p.s. A friend suggested I read your paper as well to think more about this so thank you for the comment!